# Symfony's link_to helper method ignores the third argument

Tags: php, symfony1, routes, hyperlink, helper

I'm trying to generate environment-independent links in a navigation menu with Symfony routing system. I have the following routes in `routing.yml`:

```
# Navigation menu rules
sample:
  class:   sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options: { model: Sample }

# Default rules (catch all)
homepage:
  url:    /
  param:  { module: sample, action: index }

default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

And in the navigation menu, I have the following calls to the `link_to` helper method, customized according to the actual section:

```
<?php
...
if ( $actualSection === 'sample' )
    echo link_to('Sample', 'sample', array('class' => 'actualSection'));
else
    echo link_to('Sample', 'sample');

...
?>
```

Problem is that `link_to` is generating links like:

```
<a href="/sample?class=actualSection">Samples</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="/sample" class="actualSection">Samples</a>
```

What is the correct way to use the `link_to` helper method with the routing system in order to generate the latter link?

According to [link_to documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_link_to) internal URIs should be written in 'module/action' format, so I guess the initial `/` can be omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second argument seems to be incorrect. Either you put the name of a route, prefixed by '@' (like `@sample_index` or whatever route sfDoctrineCollection generates), either you use the "module/action format" => `sample/index`.

Comment: Thanks! I was assuming that `'sample'` was pointing directly to `'sample/index'`, but that's only true when using the `default_index` route.

Comment: Yup. In this case, I think @elitalon just needs an extra "@": `echo link_to('Sample', '@sample', array('class' => 'actualSection'));`.

Comment: I couldn't get this working in 1.4.12.( and neither in 1.4.20.) when supplying params to to route. 
link_to() method checks if there is an '@' character in the second argument and uses link_to1() function. However this doesn't accept params array only options. It is never passed to it. 
Solved the problem by using link_to2() function

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
echo link_to('Sample', 'sample', array(), array('class' => 'actualSection'));
```

The first array - options for route, and second - html's attributes

Comment: +1, this is not documented is the code, but seems to be true if you look at `link_to2()`'s parameters